# Formatting "userCertificate;binary" for OpenSSL Processing

Tags: bash, openssl

**Goal:** To query an LDAP server and identify certificate expiration dates.

**Background:** I am able to dump user certificates (via ldapsearch) in the "userCertificate;binary" format. This results in data similar to the below:

`userCertificate:: MIIABUNCHMORECHARACTERSFORCERT1`

`userCertificate:: MIIABUNCHMORECHARACTERSFORCERT2`

(I believe )To process the above with OpenSSL I must format the output as below:

File1:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

`MIIABUNCHMORECHARACTERSFORCERT1`

`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

File2:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

`MIIABUNCHMORECHARACTERSFORCERT2`

`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

**Questions:**

- What is the best way to script looping through the ldapsearch results and for each entry remove "userCertificate;binary", place the certificate between the BEGIN/END tags, and then place each entry into an individual file for processing? I'm assuming this can be done with 'awk' or 'sed'.
- Is there a way to process with OpenSSL without adding the BEGIN/END tags or separating each entry into a new file?

Thank you.

Comment: Clarification: I process with OpenSSL as such "openssl x509 -in file1.cer -text".

Answer (score 1):

cat ldap_search_results.ldi | grep userCertificate | while read line; do cert=$(echo $line | awk -F '::' '{print $2}'); echo -e "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${cert}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----" | openssl x509 -text | grep -Ei 'Subject|not after'; done

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. BTW: in lieu of the grep -Ei command, you can add the arguments `-subject` and `-enddate` after the `-text. That will just show the subject and not after date.